# Problem with writing a text so the script doesnt repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write on a txt file the # of image that I'm on (ie 1, 2, etc) so the script |doesn't repeat post , but always getting this erros when debbuging, i am a newbie to programing.

Its a bot to pick top 15 images from subreddits i choose and save them, then upload to instagram. And writes a txt file to dont download same picture twice

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Luis Gomes/Desktop/Python/INSTAMEMES-master/instameme- 
NEW.py", line 100, in <module>
    memenum = int(f_content)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Code:

```
Very messy but basically used to write to a .txt file 
the # of meme that I'm on (ie 1, 2, etc) so the script doesn't repeat post 

memenum = 1 
memenum_default = 1

with open('meme.txt', 'r') as f:
    f_content = f.read()

    # before we cast to an int, check to see if f_content is empty
    if f_content:
        memenum = int(f_content)
    else:
        memenum = 1 # this 1 might need to be changed to something else

    if(memenum > 10):
        memenum = 1
    else:
        memenum = int(f_content)

    newmemenum = int(memenum)+1


'''------------------------------------- Postar fotos para o instagram API ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''

InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI("*******", "********")
InstagramAPI.login()  # login

if(memenum not in list(dankmeme_dict.values())):
    photo_path = r'Dm'+random.choice(meme_and_bpt)+str(memenum)+'.jpg'
    if(memenum not in list(meme_dict.values())):
        photo_path = r'Mm'+random.choice(dankmeme_bpt)+str(memenum)+'.jpg'
        if(memenum not in list(bpt_dict.values())):
            photo_path = r'BpT'+random.choice(dankmeme_meme)+str(memenum)+'.jpg'
else:
    photo_path = r'Om'+(meme_index[1])+str(memenum_default)+'.jpg'

with open('meme.txt', 'w') as file: #writes to .txt file the # meme so the scipt remembers for next run
    file.write(str(newmemenum)) 

print('NEW MEME# = ', newmemenum)

sys.exit()
``
```

Comment: Your file probably contained something that couldn't be interpreted as an integer. Check your file.

Comment: what is the content of `meme.txt` file ?

Comment: You should catch exceptions using [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=try%20except#handling-exceptions).

Comment: @shotgunner its blank.

Comment: @RealS3nji why do you want to read a file that contains nothing ?